# Null pointer exception - BitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized

Tags: android

Here is the code that causing rising the exception

```
 mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.pin)).position(latLng));
```

Adding the crash log:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.checkNotNull (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.zzawe (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (Unknown Source)
com.app.myapplication.fragments.BaseHomeFragment$4.onReceive (BaseHomeFragment.java:206)
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run (LoadedApk.java:1185)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6836)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Why this **BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)** rising unknown source error???

I can handle this using a null check, but that won't solve the exact problem.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: have you check your `mMap` is null or not?

Comment: is this drawable your custom or from android?

Comment: @Radhey: mMap is not null

Comment: @Koustuv: Costom drawable (pin.png image) put under drawable folder.

Comment: @SunSun try to update your code and split BitmapDescriptorFactory to a different variable check my answer

Comment: And this R is imported from your package only r8?

Comment: @SunSun i mean to say have you put null check for the `mMap` ?. edit more related code stuff in your question

Comment: R is from my package. @Radhey: mMap null check is in the code

Comment: are you checking in real device or inside emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like:

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin);                 
mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                        .icon(icon));
```

Comment: Could you please tell how this is going to solve the problem? It's just a rewriting of existing code with a new variable.

Comment: @SunSun yes please just try the code it will fix your problem

Comment: This is happening to some of the production users. I'll give it a try and accept your answer checking Crashlytics few days.

Comment: @SunSUn perfect hope it helps you, have a nice coding day!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
  BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
         .icon(icon);

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you're using a vector drawables or xml based drawables. You need to use a .png file.

```
 BitmapDescriptor icon = 
 BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin);                 
 mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(icon));
```

Comment: R.drawable.pin is a png file.